# Issues while importing php files

Tags: php, path, require-once

I am developing a website on a local test environment. From time to time I need to import classes or functions into my php pages. At first I used relative paths to import files, but for some (unexplicable) reason the PHP couldn't find those files. So I have thought it would be necessary use the following:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/mywebsite/inc/libs/functions.php'); ?>
```

The problem is when I have to upload all the pages to my remote webserver, the PHP interpreter won't find `functions.php` in that position because there is no `mywebsite` subfolder , on the other hand I can't get rid of `mywebsite` subfolder, because that would leave me with `http://localhost/inc/libs/functions.php` which leads nowhere.

So that basically means I will have to manually readjust the path to make everything work. My question is: is there a way for PHP to detect the exact folder of my website so that I don't have to change paths everytime I need to upload a php file to my webserver?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason behind impossibility of use relative path?

```
<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/inc/libs/functions.php'); ?>
```

Comment: What if he's in a different directory?

Comment: Without knowing exact path of the script including `functions.php`, we can't be sure what is going to work and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

Set the base folder with all the files you want as an include path in php.ini.

That way, when you use include () or require (), it will automatically look in the included path.

www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: I don't have access to php.ini file on my remote webserver.

Comment: Have you tried the function set_include_path() ? You don't need to use php.ini for that :-)